# Bash: Using pkill to track progress of removing a directory

Tags: bash

So I have a shell script that does some long operations, and when they do I want to just output a series of dots (.) until it's done, to show that it's running.

I'm using pkill to test that the process is running, and as long as it is it outputs another dot. This works very well for nearly every place I need it. However, one part of the process involves removing a directory, and that is where it breaks down.

Here is my code:

```
ERROR=$(rm -rf "$1" 2>&1 >/dev/null)
    while pkill -0 rm; do
        printf "."
        sleep 1
    done
    printf "\n"
```

I'm using pkill to test the rm process, but when I do, this is the output I get:

```
pkill: signalling pid 192: Operation not permitted

pkill: signalling pid 326: Operation not permitted

.pkill: signalling pid 61: Operation not permitted
```

My script runs up until the dot-output code, including the folder deletion, but then it stops and just outputs those three lines over and over again until I forcibly kill the process.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on? I feel like it's not able to work with the rm operation, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some processes matching `rm` that you have no rights sending signals. E.g. on my system: `pkill -0 rm` gives 
`pkill: killing pid 1394 failed: Operation not permitted` and `ps -aux | grep rm` shows a `dirmngr` (with `rm` matches as substring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `pkill` is sending `kill(PID, SIG_0)` for the processes *matched by Regex pattern `rm`*. For some matched processes (shown by the PIDs), you don't have sufficient permission to send `SIG_0` to get the process status.

You can use `-x` (`--exact`) option (no Regex) to match only process(es) with exact name `rm` (given there is no `rm` by other users running):

```
pkill -0 -x rm
```

or use `pgrep`

```
pgrep -x rm
```

Better mention your username:

```
pkill -0 -x -u username rm
pgrep -x -u username rm
```

Comment: This is great, except for the position of the exact flag. It should be pkill -0 -u username -x rm. That's what worked for me

Comment: @user2223059 oops..you are right, the signal should be at first..i have written it from head..fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not putting `rm` into the background, so when pkill is being run, presumably it's finding processes owned by other users and is not able to kill them because you cannot kill another user's process unless you are root.

Since you are spawning the process within the script, if you correctly background the `rm` then you can get the PID of the `rm` job from `$!` and use `kill` instead of `pkill`.

You should run the rm command and properly background it. The following untested code *should* do what you're trying to do:

```
rm -rf "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
RMPID=$!
while kill -0 $RMPID 2>/dev/null; do
    printf "."
    sleep 1
done
printf "\n"
wait $RMPID
RESULT=$? 
if (( $RESULT != 0 )); then
   printf "Error when deleting $1\n"
   exit 1
fi
```

You can read the bash documentation for more details on `wait` and `$!` and `$?`

Comment: I originally tried using kill for this, but I could never get it to work properly. pkill worked for me, so that's why I ran with it. Following your directions here, I got kill working for a moment, but at the end of the loop it gives me a "no such process" error after outputting a few times.

Comment: Also the output that way has seemed to work well for me. I'm still relatively new to shell scripting, but redirecting 2>&1 has gotten me the error output, which >/dev/null has sent away all other output. This has successfully worked for me in several other places in my code.

Comment: You're right, ordering of the redirects matters and my comment would have applied had they been reversed.

Comment: I've added the required redirect to take care of the first issue